# Windows Phone 8 - Culture Specific App for local stores

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm working with the windows phone 8 SDK and I'm trying to get my app into the various local stores around the world.
When I upload my app, I'm able to add store title/description/screenshots for all the supported languages of my app.

However, I'm not getting an option for both spain and mexico, australia, austria etc.
Only english, english international, spanish, french, german, italian, norwegian, swedish etc

In my project file, my `<SupportedCultures>` looks as follows

```
<SupportedCultures>nb-NO%3ben%3bit%3bes%3bde%3bfr%3ben-GB%3bfr-FR%3bde-AT%3bde-DE%3bit-IT%3bes-MX%3bes-ES%3bsv-SE</SupportedCultures>
```

Under properties for my app, supported cultures looks like the screenshot below

[image]

In WMAppManifest.xml, all the neutral and specific cultures are checked 
spanish
spanish(mexico)
spanish(spain)
english
english(great britain)
english(usa)
english(australia)
and so on...

I have created .resx files for every language and cultures;
AppResources.de-DE.resx, .es-ES.resx, .es-MX.resx etc

When I submit my app to the store, I'm not able to select a store description for other than spanish and english, not for instance mexico and spain, australia and usa

Am I missing something? (probably:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you got your syntax wrong, the main project file contains the languages separated by semicolon:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
         <SupportedCultures>en;es-ES;es-MX</SupportedCultures>
```

Comment: I did not enter those my self, for some reason they are listed url encoded. I'll try to edit it manually and post back.

Comment: I tried to manually edit it to <SupportedCultures>nb-NO;en;it;es;de;fr;en-GB;fr-FR;de-AT;de-DE;it-IT;es-MX;es-ES;sv-SE</SupportedCultures> - rebuild, upload xap - same issue, only culture neutral languages are in the drop down list.